# Selenium Server on MacOS El Capitan won't start as standalone (NoSuchMethodError)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-server

I try to run selenium server on MacOS 10.11.
Installed via brew (=selenium server 2.53.1) 
Installed JDK: 1.8.0_45

When I try to start the server I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities.edge()Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities;
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.<clinit>(DefaultDriverSessions.java:54)
at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.assembleHandlers(SeleniumServer.java:383)
at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.createJettyServer(SeleniumServer.java:343)
at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.<init>(SeleniumServer.java:298)
at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.main(SeleniumServer.java:239)
at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher$1.launch(GridLauncher.java:58)
at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(GridLauncher.java:127)
```

I also tried downloading the most current version (jar) from the selenium website (selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar) but the error is the same.

Has anyone an idea what the problem is?

**Edit:**
To clarify this question:
I'm trying to run the selenium server in standalone mode. The problem comes already when trying to start up the server in standalone mode. 
("java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar")

I followed the instructions at https://phpunit.de/manual/4.8/en/selenium.html

It works fine when I use Linux, but it doesn't seem to work on the Mac.

It also works to start the server in "hub"-mode (adding the flag "-role hub") but not in the standalone mode. 
I did not find any related issue in the github repository for selenium server.

Comment: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4334 please look  into it

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade Can you please clarify what I should look into? I have looked into the issue you mention before but it is about  an application using selenium server. I try to start up the selenium server by itself without any other application.

Comment: it has chain in github discussion about the same exception, I think it will be helpful to you